# weird mktime behavior in standard c

Tags: c, strptime

With follow code, the strptime output is correct but mktime is completely off, can someone help me out here?

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int ddate;
    double dt;
    char dstr1[20],dstr2[20];
    time_t s1,s2;
    struct tm d1,d2;

    strptime("04/06/2015","%m/%d/%Y",&d1); 
    strptime("08/06/2015","%m/%d/%Y",&d2);
    strftime(dstr1,20,"%Y-%m-%d",&d1);
    strftime(dstr2,20,"%Y-%m-%d",&d2); 
    printf("%s,%s\n",dstr1,dstr2);
    s1=mktime(&d1);
    s2=mktime(&d2);
    printf(ctime(&s1));
    printf(ctime(&s2));
    return(0);
}
```

```
=== output ====
2015-04-06,2015-08-06
Mon Apr  6 01:51:31 2015
Sun Jan 14 07:16:48 113900
```

Comment: Using `strptime()` means you're using POSIX, not Standard C.  However, that's not a major problem except in your terminology.

Comment: Please don't put multiple statements on a single line.

Comment: Don't pass random strings to `printf`. Use the format specifiers.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `d1` and `d2` contain garbage before you call `strptime` and it is only setting the year, month and day of the `struct tm`. So `mktime` is dealing with the random values in the other fields as best it can.

Add in a call to `memset` or use some other means to clear the content of the two variables and the code works as expected.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
int main () 

    {
    int ddate;
    double dt;
    char dstr1[20],dstr2[20];
    time_t s1,s2;
    struct tm d1,d2;

    memset(&d1,0,sizeof(d1));
    memset(&d2,0,sizeof(d2));
    strptime("04/06/2015","%m/%d/%Y",&d1); 
    strptime("08/06/2015","%m/%d/%Y",&d2);
    strftime(dstr1,20,"%Y-%m-%d",&d1);
    strftime(dstr2,20,"%Y-%m-%d",&d2); 
    printf("%s,%s\n",dstr1,dstr2);
    s1=mktime(&d1);
    s2=mktime(&d2);
    printf("%s",ctime(&s1));
    printf("%s",ctime(&s2));
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Or `struct tm d1 = { 0 };`.  I'd just come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Or `struct tm d1 = { .tm_mday = 1 };` since `tm_mday` is 1-based. Although your `strptime` sets `tm_mday` anyway, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks guys, that fix the issue. So basically it's because I'm not using the time portion of the structure tm, so it comes up with random time and when converting with mktime, these random time add random days to the existing ones. Is that right? If I need to reuse d1 & d2 in a loop, do I need to clean their contents every time, or just the first time?

Comment: This answer assumes DST is 0 for the 2 dates

Comment: Usually setting .is_dst = -1 is prudent before the mktime call.  Try 2 dates, one in December and 1 in July.

Answer (score 0):

The C11 description for [`mktime`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.3p2) is

> **Description**
>
> 2. The `mktime` function converts the broken-down time, expressed as
>      local time, in the structure pointed to by `timeptr` into a calendar
>      time value with the same encoding as that of the values returned by
>      the time function. The original values of the `tm_wday` and `tm_yday`
>      components of the structure are ignored, and **the original values of
>      the other components are not restricted to the ranges indicated
>      above.** 320) On successful completion, the values of the `tm_wday` and
>      `tm_yday` components of the structure are set appropriately, and the
>      other components are set to represent the specified calendar time, but
>      with their values forced to the ranges indicated above; the final
>      value of `tm_mday` is not set until `tm_mon` and `tm_year` are determined.

**(emphasis mine)**

---

The garbage in `d1` is the reason. I wrote a simplified program:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    time_t s1;
    struct tm d1;

    strptime("04/06/2015","%m/%d/%Y",&d1); 
    printf("%02d:%02d:%02d\n", d1.tm_hour, d1.tm_min, d1.tm_sec);
    s1=mktime(&d1);
    puts(ctime(&s1));
    return(0);
}
```

The output is (for example)

```
910751933:01:00
Thu May  8 05:00:01 105913
```

I.e. it is Friday October 19 2018 at 910751933 hours 1 minutes and 0 seconds.

Unlike `mktime`, `strftime` only uses those fields of the broken-down structure that are required by the format.